# ICoreAuthenticationProvider NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Compilation of project was successful but in a runtime this error appeared:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/graph/httpcore/ICoreAuthenticationProvider
```

Implementation of ClientCredentialProvider
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Class `ClientCredentialProvider` needed `ICoreAuthenticationProvider` interface which is in artifact `microsoft-graph-core`.

Just add this dependency to maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```